# Does Postsharp .pssym files are required as part of the product installation?

Tags: postsharp

I'm using postsharp and would like to know if these files .pssym are required for our product build/install process ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pssym files are not required for build or as part of a production installation.

Pssym files contains information about aspects applied to your code. PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio uses them to underline source code elements enhanced by an aspect and for source code analysis.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jakub!